# MySQL issue - querying the database attributes with 'string_value' returns 0 for some attributes and ALL rows for others why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following format.

```
|id | int_col|
--------------
1   | 0      |
2   | 0      |
--------------
```

The DDL is defined below:

`id` - is the primary key - it is also set to auto increment

`int_col` - is an attribute

I tried the below queries:

```
Select * from table_name where id='string_value';
```

Returns 0 rows.

```
Select * from table_name where int_col = 'string_value';
```

Returns all rows

I am not sure as to why it has returned all rows. I expected it to return 0 rows for both queries.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418fe65/1) this behaviour.

Comment: I have edited my question with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it short: **do not compare strings and integers in MySQL**. This can lead to unpredictable results such as those you are seeing.

As per [MySQL conversion rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html), comparing a string and an integer actually results in both values being under the hood converted to floating point numbers, and then compared. The documentation warns :

> Comparisons that use floating-point numbers [...] are approximate because such numbers are inexact. This might lead to results that appear inconsistent.

Further in the doc, another disclaimers can be found that specifically relates to integer/string comparison :

> Furthermore, the conversion from string to floating-point and from integer to floating-point do not necessarily occur the same way. The integer may be converted to floating-point by the CPU, whereas the string is converted digit by digit in an operation that involves floating-point multiplications.
>
> The results shown will vary on different systems, and can be affected by factors such as computer architecture or the compiler version or optimization level.

Finally, here is an example of (possible) conversion discrepancy, also from MySQL documentation:

```
mysql> SELECT '18015376320243458' = 18015376320243458;
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT '18015376320243459' = 18015376320243459;
        -> 0
```

Comment: Which version are you using? I can't reproduce your example.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: the example comes straight from the documentation. I just now tested this in [a DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Rvmr3UEHfijtW6n2GdXnR/0) and I am not able to reproduce it either, on any version of MySQL supported in the fiddle...

Comment: Documentation says: *The results shown will vary on different systems, and can be affected by factors such as computer architecture or the compiler version or optimization level.*... Might explain why we are not able to reproduce...

Comment: "In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers." - This is sooooooooo wrong. And also not (always) true. If I have `id` as INT PK, `where id = '1234567890'` will use the index. But that wouldn't be possible if the engine would cast the `id` to float/double.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: I do agree that MySQL conversion rules, as explained in the (latest !) docs, are, to say the least, simplistic (and to say the worst : wrong). And I can see also some cases where implicit conversion works properly... Bottom line, I understand that the docs basically discourages it.